# Struggling with find

Tags: find

I have the following scenario:

My directory-tree looks like this:

```
/export/home1/user1/profile.V2
/export/home1/user2/profile.V2
```

my find command should find all profile.V2 directories:

```
find /export/home1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -iname "profile.V2" -exec ls -lho --quoting-style=escape {} \;
```

but it doesn't. I think "find" looks for "profile.V2" in /export/home1 and not in all scanned subtrees...

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the flag `-maxdepth 1` you are telling it to look only in the `/export/home1/` directory, not in the subtrees. I would just remove the `-maxdepth` (and `-mindepth`) flag if not necessary for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks, that works!I tried this before, but it was the "ls" command what makes me confused!

Comment: @EuC_HAW if this answer solved your problem please _accept_ it with the tick mark next to the number of the left-hand side.